# How can we sketch 3D Interlayers?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, 3d

I want to sketch this image

[image]

but I cannot sketch those curved interlayers. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture} 

%\useasboundingbox (0.5,0,0) rectangle (10,8,0);

 %Glass
\filldraw[ball color=black!50!gray,shading angle=5, fill opacity=0.7, line join=round, draw=none] (1.25,1.2,0) -- (9.75,1.2,0) -- (9.75,1.5,0) --(1.25,1.5,0)--cycle;   

\shade[ball color=black!50!gray,shading angle=165, fill opacity=0.7, line join=round, draw=none]  (1.25,1.5,0) --(9.75,1.5,0) -- (8,3.7,0) -- (3,3.7,0) -- cycle;


%ITO
\filldraw[ball color=blue!80!green,shading angle=5, fill opacity=0.7, line join=round, draw=none] (1.65,2,0) rectangle (10.19,3,2.2);
\shade[ball color=blue!80!green,shading angle=5, fill opacity=0.7, line join=round, draw=none] (1.635,2.15,0) --(9.36,2.15,0) -- (8.03,3.81,0) -- (2.97,3.81,0) --cycle;

%NiO
\filldraw[ball color=green!50!black!80!blue,shading angle=5, fill opacity=0.7, line join=round, draw=none] (1.9,2.5,0) rectangle (9.93,3.5,2.2);
\shade[ball color=green!50!black!80!blue,shading angle=5, fill opacity=0.7, line join=round, draw=none] (1.885,2.65,0) --(9.1,2.65,0) -- (8.03,3.925,0) -- (2.97,3.925,0) --cycle;


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Also, I want to have those **colors** and also **rotate** my object the same as that sample image but I could not do them in latex! Please help to modify and complete this code.

Comment: I suggest to clean up your preamble, as not all packages are needed to create your drawing, and one is even duplicated. It's also a nice idea to post a screenshot of the drawing your posetd code creates. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an other way to do it.

#### Tikz doesn't provide wire frames

Though the 3D package does provide some mapping to the 3 axes x,y and z, it's no wireframing. I.e. you can't build a wireframe and rotate your 3D-drawing as you want and fill areas or so. It's simply not made for that purpose (yet?).

So if you have access to a 3D-CAD tool or to a 3D-animation tool which can do it, just use that, export to pdf, png etc., and include it via package `graphicx` as an ordinary image.

You can also have the import inside a nodes text like so:

```
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics ...};
```

#### Approach it as an artist would do

So as an artist, you'd simply sketch it, taking the 3D-illusion into account.

This implies, you also draw you flat sheets pre-rotated, in 2D, just as an artist sees it.

For the curved sheets the code below may give you a start. It's not perfect yet, and you can introduce your ball and shading effects.

So all you need to do is to derive resonable coordinates for a single sheet, e.g. from using `Paint.net` or similar programs:

[image: coordinates]

#### Let's go through the main points

The **basic idea** is to provide `"\pics"`, which draw just one curved sheet (in pre-perceived 3D-to-2D-mapping), place as many as you need and impact on their colors.

So the curved sheets should be used like

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic at (0,0)     {curv={red!70/red!100/red!60}};
    \pic at (-.1,-.3) {curv={orange!70/orange!100/orange!60}};
    ...
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

So the `pic` is called `curv` and it accepts `3 parameters` (for the colors), which I'd like to separate by a `/`.

Next, define `code` for `pic` `curv`, e.g. in a separate `\tikzset` statement:

```
\tikzset{
    pics/curv/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{% accept 3 color fills
      code={
        % ~~~ sheet ~~~~~~~~
        \draw[fill=#1] (2.2,-1.4) to [out=170, in=-60] (1.2,-.5)
...
      }
    }
}
```

The syntax is a bit different, as I pass 3 parameters as arguments `args`.

Instead of defining the curvatures via angles in `to [in=,out=]` you can also use the Bezier-approach using `.. controls ..` .

That's it.

For the sake of illusion, below I rotated the 3rd sheet slightly, but it's probably better to define a separate curved sheet for this purpose.

Also note that by choice of perspective the *closing black top sheet* in your posted drawing may be obsolete, and you may want to clip the picture to the right, or extend the sheets as needed.

#### Result and code

[image: result]

Please note that for the sake of keeping the illusion I shifted the `\pic` s slightly towards the lower left.

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\tikzset{
    pics/curv/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{% accept 3 color fills
      code={
        % ~~~ sheet ~~~~~~~~
        \draw[fill=#1] (2.2,-1.4) to [out=170, in=-60] (1.2,-.5)
        -- (0,0) 
        to [out=280,in=140] (.6,-.9) 
        -- (2,-1.5) -- (2.2,-1.5) -- cycle;
        
        % ~~~ thickness top ~~~
        \draw[fill=#2] (0,0) -- ++(50:1mm) -- ++(1.2,-.5)
        -- ++(-140:1mm) -- cycle;
        
        % ~~~ thickness side ~~~
        \draw[fill=#3] (2.2,-1.4) to [out=170, in=-60] (1.2,-.5) -- 
        ++(50:1mm) to [out=-60,in=170] (2.2,-1.3) -- cycle;
      }
    }
}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic at (0,0)     {curv={red!70/red!100/red!60}};
    \pic at (-.1,-.3) {curv={orange!70/orange!100/orange!60}};
    \pic[rotate=4] at (-.2,-.7) {curv={blue!70/blue!100/blue!60}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 10):

This is not an attempt to precisely reproduce the screen shot of your post, but rather a way to generate such "layers" with relative ease. You can customize the appearance by, among other things, adjusting the `color map`, plot function and the loop parameters.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-1,xmax=0,ymin=-1,ymax=0,
        hide axis, 
        view={-45}{45}]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3,7,11,15}{
        \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain=-1:0,domain y=-1:0,point meta=#1+z] {0.1*#1+#1*0.1*x*x}; 
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please let me know how can we give them a "thickness" to those sheets?